# org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms

I am following the examples at [Introducing Spring Framework 6'](https://github.com/Apress/introducing-spring-framework6), specifically the [chapter 9](https://github.com/Apress/introducing-spring-framework6/tree/main/chapter09/src/main/java/md) where I cannot successfully run the example regarding JMS.

The following setup:

(Main class)

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableJms
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyDocsApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyDocsApp.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  CommandLineRunner send(JmsPublisher publisher) {
    return args -> {
      IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).forEach(
        (value) -> {
          var uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
          publisher.send(
            new Document(
              "document " + uuid,
              "/documents/doc" + uuid
            ));
        }
      );
    };
  }
```

The publisher

```java
@Component
public class JmsPublisher {
  private final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  public JmsPublisher(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
  }

  public void send(Document document) {
    jmsTemplate.send("documents", session -> session.createObjectMessage(document));
  }
}
```

The `document` class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="document")
public class Document implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  Integer id;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  String name;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  String location;

  Document() {
  }
  Document(String name, String location) {
    setName(name);
    setLocation(location);
  }

// getter/setter omitted
```

The gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id "application"
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
}

dependencies {
    implementation  \
      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.6'
    implementation  \
      'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis:3.0.6'
    implementation  \
      'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'
 //   implementation  \
 //    'org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server:2.24.0'
}

application {
    mainClass.set("md.MyDocsApp")
}
```

My problem now is that I fail to see where I need to start a JMS server. What do I need to do to get rid of

```
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:703) ~[artemis-core-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
```

The complete stacktrace with log output is the following:

```
2023-04-24T09:27:11.046+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] md.MyDocsApp                             : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-24T09:27:11.268+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-24T09:27:11.296+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-24T09:27:11.550+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-24T09:27:11.578+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-04-24T09:27:11.744+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-24T09:27:11.852+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:7ef74512-9dd7-4cc1-9e98-e4c392d01864 user=SA
2023-04-24T09:27:11.853+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-24T09:27:11.874+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-04-24T09:27:12.312+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-24T09:27:12.317+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-24T09:27:12.767+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory         : Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection

jakarta.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:867) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:284) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:279) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:427) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:352) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:327) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:242) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:412) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:380) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.establishSharedConnection(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:861) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStart(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:292) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:277) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.start(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:655) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.java:242) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.start(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.java:205) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:587) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at md.MyDocsApp.main(MyDocsApp.java:18) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:703) ~[artemis-core-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:865) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    ... 28 common frames omitted

2023-04-24T09:27:12.777+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] md.MyDocsApp                             : Started MyDocsApp in 1.947 seconds (process running for 2.267)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:38899', transport: 'socket'
2023-04-24T09:27:17.107+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-04-24T09:27:17.117+02:00 ERROR 22314 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:772) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:753) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:317) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at md.MyDocsApp.main(MyDocsApp.java:18) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:311) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:184) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:510) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:587) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at md.JmsPublisher.send(JmsPublisher.java:15) ~[main/:na]
    at md.MyDocsApp.lambda$send$0(MyDocsApp.java:27) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:617) ~[na:na]
    at md.MyDocsApp.lambda$send$1(MyDocsApp.java:24) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: jakarta.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:867) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:284) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:279) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:427) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:352) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:327) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:242) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:497) ~[spring-jms-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:703) ~[artemis-core-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:865) ~[artemis-jakarta-client-2.26.0.jar:2.26.0]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2023-04-24T09:27:17.121+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-24T09:27:17.122+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-04-24T09:27:17.123+02:00  INFO 22314 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: You need to start a JMS server, without a server nothing will be send. Which is probably explained in the book (which I suggest you get instead of just the code). That being said, why the `@Enable*` annotations, those aren't really needed in a Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this problem is actually quite simple. I had to uncomment these lines in the `gradle.build` file:

```
   implementation  \
    'org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server:2.24.0'
```

(Too bad that the authors decided to leave this passage without any comment...)

This means whenever you have this problem `ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.` check that you have started any JMS server as the comment from @M-Deinum already suggests.